# How to pin one SKPhysicBody to another without both falling

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am trying to join two SKPhysicsBodies together so that the one on top stays in place and the one below falls with gravity but is attached with a joint.  Imagine two rectangles, one on top and one below.  The one on top stays in place "floating" and the one below is attached with a joint and can move (swing perhaps or bounce etc)

When I attempt to create this, both nodes fall with gravity even if I set the affectedByGravity to NO.

```
self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -9.8);


    SKLabelNode *myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"myFont"];

    myLabel.text = @"Hello, World!";
    myLabel.fontSize = 30;
    myLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                   CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    myLabel.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:myLabel.frame.size];
    myLabel.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

     [self addChild:myLabel];



    SKLabelNode *myLabel2 = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"myFont"];

    myLabel2.text = @"Hello, World!";
    myLabel2.fontSize = 30;
    myLabel2.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                   CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    myLabel2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:myLabel2.frame.size];


    [self addChild:myLabel2];


    CGPoint anchor = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                 CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    SKPhysicsJointFixed* fixedJoint = [SKPhysicsJointFixed jointWithBodyA:myLabel.physicsBody
                                                                    bodyB:myLabel2.physicsBody
                                                                   anchor:anchor];
    [self.scene.physicsWorld addJoint:fixedJoint];
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `dynamic` property for the static body to `NO`?

Comment: That did the trick!  Post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `dynamic` property of the static body to `NO`, and that will cause the body to ignore all forces and impulses, including gravity.